# How to create immersive fullscreen application in React Native (Expo)?

Tags: react-native, expo, android-fullscreen, android-immersive

I want to create **Immersive Fullscreen** application with **React Native (Expo)**. After many hour's of research online, I only got solutions which are applicable for bare react native project only which include editing **MainActivity.java** file.

From the [Documentation for app.json - expo](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/), I changed the app.json by adding following lines

```json
    "androidNavigationBar": {
        "visible": "immersive",
    }
```

[Before Adding the above lines, my application would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFCoa.jpg)

[However, after adding the lines and recompiling the application it looks like this *(Changed Black Color into Red)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akcaN.jpg)

[Unedited Image ↑](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLKNk.jpg)

What I want is to remove the ***black part** (Red in second image)* - replacement of **StatusBar** with the `<View />` of my application.

*app.json*

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Fullscreen",
    "slug": "Fullscreen",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "androidStatusBar": {
        "translucent": true,
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "androidNavigationBar": {
        "visible": "immersive",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [expo-full-screen](https://github.com/Luluno01/expo-full-screen) by simply installing it into your expo managed project without needing to modify native files:

```
npx expo install git+https://github.com/Luluno01/expo-full-screen.git
```

Here is the API Reference [here](https://github.com/Luluno01/expo-full-screen?tab=readme-ov-file#api-reference)